# Converting a rosbag.db3 file to .pcd

Tags: ros2, slam, mapping, pcl, bag-to-pcd

I've been trying to convert a rosbag which i've generated after running the [kiss-icp](https://github.com/PRBonn/kiss-icp) algorithm (so output is sensor_msg/msg/PointCloud2) into a 3D map of the environment, by converting it into a .pcd format using the humble-pcl-ros library. For some reason it recognises other .cpp files as executables in the pcl_ros library (filter_cropbox_node, pcd_to_pointlcloud etc.) but not bag_to_pcd, leading to:

```
ros2 run pcl_ros bag_to_pcd.cpp /data/myrosbag.db3 /kiss/local_map /data/map1

No executable found
```

Is there any way to fix this or is there perhaps an easier method or package to use to convert my rosbag.db3 file into a 3D map? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expecting the name of the executable, not the source file cpp:

Try:

```
ros2 run pcl_ros bag_to_pcd /data/myrosbag.db3 /kiss/local_map /data/map1
```

You need to include your node bag_to_pcd node in the build and installation process, in other words, add the node to the CMakeLists.txt file of the package to ensure it gets compiled and linked properly.

Comment: Made the edit in the CMakeList.txt file but now the build for pcl_ros is failing in the '#include <rosbag/bag.h>' line in bag_to_pcd.cpp, probably because i'm missing the package (rosbag is deprecated, think rosbag2 is now the one that is used). I've managed to convert my .db3 into a bunch of .pcds using this library [link](https://github.com/xmfcx/rosbag2_to_pcd/blob/main/README.md) instead, but thanks for the help anyways, learnt a bit more about how the build process works.